# AWS Quicksight, Redshift "A subquery that refers to a nested table cannot contain WINDOW operation"

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-redshift, amazon-quicksight, amazon-redshift-spectrum

The error message is:

```
sourceErrorCode:    
500310
sourceErrorMessage:     
[Amazon](500310) Invalid operation: Spectrum nested query error Details: 
----------------------------------------------- 
error: Spectrum nested query error code: 8001 context: A subquery that 
refers to a nested table cannot contain WINDOW operation. 
query: 0 
location: nested_query_rewriter.cpp:756 
process: padbmaster
```

And this happens when I add data from Redshift Spectrum into Quicksight and try to create some visualizations. I understand that Redshift Spectrum has some [nested data limitations](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/dg/nested-data-restrictions.html) but I am not writing the queries myself (since I'm using Quicksight).

Is there anything I can do for this? I can use Athena with the same data and it works fine.

The custom SQL Expression I use on Quicksight is:

```
select
d.metadata.x as x,
d.metadata.y as y,
d.metadata.z as z,
d.metadata.w as w,
d.metadata.a as a,
r.timestamp.seconds as ts_seconds,
r.timestamp.microseconds as ts_microseconds,
r.b as b
from s3.data as d, d.results r
```

(obviously mock fields)

Comment: Please can you take a look in the redshift query log / aws console to see the actual sql that is being executed, and update your question with that info?

Comment: I enabled logging for my Redshift cluster and run some queries both on Redshift (Spectrum) and Quicksight. No logs were created, not sure if I did something wrong

Comment: you enabled logging? what did you do? where did you look?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the end, to make everything easier, I flattened the data